# Populating an ObservableCollection of ObservableCollection, delimited by two database columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

My database is as follows :

```
ID   Date   Number   NumberIWishToRecord
```

What I wish to do is use a Linq-to-SQL query to populate an `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<CustomClass>>`.

What I want is select only the rows were `Number == a given parameter`.

`ID` refers to a person, what I want to do is get all the information about a person and store it in an `ObservableCollection`, so I will have an `ObservableCollection<CustomClass>`, with each `CustomClass` holding information about only one row, and each `ObservableCollection<CustomClass>` holding information about only one person (recorded on different days).

I then wish to select an `ObservableCollection` of the `ObservableCollection<CustomClass>` which will hold information on all people!

So, some sample data :

```
ID   Date          Number   NumberIWishToRecord
1    27-06-2012    0.1933   25
1    28-06-2012    0.1933   27
1    29-06-2012    0.1933   29
2    14-06-2012    0.1933   412
2    15-06-2012    0.1741   321
```

So when I run my method, I want to return only the Numbers of the given parameter, in my case I will choose 0.1933.

I then want both rows where ID = 1 to be saved in an `ObservableCollection<CustomClass>`, and the single row where `ID == 2` to be saved in another `ObservableCollection<CustomClass>`. Then, both of these `ObservableCollections` will be held in their own `ObservableCollection`! To illustrate :

```
ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<CustomClass>>
     ObservableCollection<CustomClass>
         1    27-06-2012    0.1933   25
         1    28-06-2012    0.1933   27
         1    29-06-2012    0.1933   29
     ObservableCollection<CustomClass>
         2    14-06-2012    0.1933   412
```

How would I write a query in linq to sql that would do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just write a standard query syntax Linq expression to achieve this, you adapt it for your tables.

```
        var rowsById = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<row>>(
            from r in _rows
            where r.number == 1.2
            group r by r.ID into rowIdGroup
            select new ObservableCollection<row>(rowIdGroup));
```

If you need to convert data from the row into the CustomClass:

```
        var rowsById = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<CustomClass>>(
            from r in _rows
            where r.number == 1.2
            group r by r.ID into rowIdGroup
            select new ObservableCollection<CustomClass>(
                rowIdGroup.Select(r => new CustomClass
                                        {
                                            ID = r.ID,
                                            Number = r.number // add more
                                        })));
```

Or if you prefer query syntax in all the expression:

```
        var rowsById = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<CustomClass>>(
            from r in _rows
            where r.number == 1.2
            group r by r.ID into rowIdGroup
            select new ObservableCollection<CustomClass>(
                from gr in rowIdGroup select new CustomClass
                                        {
                                            ID = gr.ID,
                                            Number = gr.number
                                        }));
```